# What are indicators that someone has a ghost writer?

Tags: publications, ethics, research-misconduct

After reading about [paper mills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_paper_mill), and knowing that there are companies that offer ghostwriting for bachelor theses, at least in Switzerland and Germany, I asked myself if there are methods to detect ghostwriting.  While this kind of service may be acceptable in some domains, in academia, having a ghostwriter may violate principles of scientific integrity. Unlike plagiarism, however, it seems to be much more difficult to find out if someone has a ghostwriter. Nevertheless, is there evidence that would point to it? I can only think of metadata of manuscripts (in case the ghostwriter forgot to clear his traces). I've certainly had students in the past who surprised me with their research paper because it didn't match my impression at all, but of course that's not really an indication.

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't conform to principles of scientific integrity? I'm pretty sure that Stephen Hawking had a lot of help with getting the words on paper. That doesn't imply that the ideas weren't his, of course. What matters is where the ideas come from.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think Hawking wasn't transparent on this. I am talking about researchers who are not transparent on this.

Comment: How much of this do you fear goes on? Why do you think it is a problem worth spending time on? If someone wants to "fake it" metadata isn't going to stop them. Unusual changes in writing style could have many explanations - multiple authors, paper developed over a very long time line, ... Do you have an example of abuse?

Comment: Maybe the question is not whether getting a ghost writer is OK, but instead whether that guy should be added as an author of the paper.

Comment: @GEdgar Under the increasingly-popular [ICMJE authorship guidelines](http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html), to qualify for authorship, an individual has to be involved _both_ in the execution of the research _and_ in the composition of the paper - so in the case I think we're talking about here, no-one would qualify to be listed as an author!  I wonder what will happen if/when a paper gets submitted to a journal with a blank author list for this reason.

Comment: @DanielHatton, I hope that contributing to the composition means little more than proof-reading (parts of) it. In a group effort it is useful if the "best" writer does the composition.

Comment: @Buffy The actual wording in the guidelines is 'Drafting the work or revising it critically for important intellectual content'... and to qualify for authorship one has to do both that and 'Substantial contributions to the conception or design of the work; or the acquisition, analysis, or interpretation of data for the work' (and a couple of other things too, but those correspond to traditional elements of academic ethics).

Comment: I can imagine a team writing initial drafts in its native language, then having an individual unaffiliated with the team translate it to another.  Is that an example of your concerns?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/160269/13240

Comment: This question is unclear; Are you grading student papers?  Are you a journal editor?  Are you an academic publisher?  Each might have different answers.

Comment: I do research and I do grade papers. Why would the answer differ based on the setting? The question is not about the consequences of ghostwriting for the student or the researcher, it's about known methods to find out who has a ghostwriter.

Comment: I am having a hard time even defining a ghostwriter on an research article.  If you narrow this question, it might get an answer.

Comment: @TerryLoring Variant 1: persons A, B, and C have done some research.  They then hire person D, who was not involved in doing the research, to write up the findings into a paper.  Persons A, B, and C appear in the author list, person D doesn't appear in the author list, nor even in the acknowledgements.

Comment: Variant 2: no research has taken place, but persons A, B, and C want to publish a paper.  Therefore, they hire person D to produce some research findings and write them up into a paper.  Again, persons A, B, and C appear in the author list, person D doesn't appear in the author list, nor even in the acknowledgements.  Notice that, in this variant, while persons A, B, and C are probably reckless as to whether the findings are fabricated, they also probably don't know for sure that the findings are fabricated.

Comment: Variant 3: persons, A, B, and C have done some research and written up the findings into a paper, but they have a conflict of interest that they don't want to declare.  Therefore, they hire person D (who was involved neither in doing the research nor in writing the paper) to appear as sole author of the paper in order to conceal the involvement of persons A, B, and C.

Comment: Variant 4: persons A, B, and C have done some research together. A should write a first draft of the manuscript, but because of some reasons (lack of competence, time etc.), she hires person D to write the manuscript.

Answer (score 3):

The utility of this answer depends on why you are seeking this information, but this comes from my own experience.

As a student, I was asked to help jog the memory of a researcher on some topics they had been working on in a collaborative project. This involved reading the papers of the collaborators, summarizing them, and figuring out how they all worked together. I wrote this all into one document, emphasized that they were notes only (not polished in any way), and did not give permission to use my work other than its intended use. I later found that the researcher published my work verbatim and claimed it as their own. After raising this issue as far as I could, I found that I was called a "ghostwriter" against my will.

Based on this experience, here are a few remarks:

- When talking to them, the researcher could not explain the works in any sort of detail other than what I had given them for notes (it had been a while since they had worked on the topic).
- Some members of the institution are aware that the researcher did not write their own work because I spoke up. This was formally documented.
- As you noted in the question, metadata revealed that I had written large portions of the document rather than the researcher.
- My writing style and the researcher's writing style differed considerably (they are not a native English speaker). If you were familiar with their work at all, mine would have stuck out like a sore thumb. Stylometry tools could have been used as well.

If you were looking to detect ghostwriters in students, you could employ a few strategies to help figure it out:

- Give them an oral component to explain their answers in more detail.
- Ask them to submit assignments electronically to have a paper trail.
- Have them submit smaller assignments to reveal their writing style. This would not work if they had a ghostwriter for every assignment.

Comment: Ok, this covers many aspects of the issue I had thought about but wasn't sure they could really be relevant. Can you explore a little bit more on the metadata, was your name in the word file or something like that?